# Using Zones in Firewalld to Block Outbound Access

Tags: centos, firewalld

I want to provide limited access to a machine which runs CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009.

For this purpose, I changed the default zone to a new zone called custom and applied a configuration as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<zone>
  <service name="ssh"/>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="5901"/>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="5902"/>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="5903"/>
  <rule family="ipv4">
    <source address="192.168.2.15"/>
    <drop/>
  </rule>
</zone>
```

With this configuration, users still have access to the other computers or web. Is it also possible to block such kind of connections in Firewalld?

Answer (score 1):

To block outbound access for specific services or destinations, you should create a custom Firewalld zone with the desired restrictions.

1. Use the firewall-cmd command to create a custom zone.
2. Define Rules for Outbound Access.
3. Set the Default Zone, if you want this custom zone to be the default for outbound traffic
4. Reload Firewalld

To block outgoing internet access, you can add this rules to your castom zone.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=block-outgoing --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="IP_machine" drop'
```

Edit

For the last edit.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone={name zone}
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone={name zone} --add-service=ssh
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone={name zone} --add-service=dns
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone={name zone} --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" drop'
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Edit

```
</rule>
  <rule family="ipv4">
    <outbound/>
    <drop/>
</rule>
```

Comment: I applied to add this rule but I can still ping to remote machines and web services.

Comment: Have you verified that the rule was taken by the firewall and that it is functioning?

Comment: Yes, I did. `firewall-cmd --get-default-zone` returns the name of the new zone in the user's terminal.

Comment: Have you tried reboot the firewall?

Comment: I tried to install iptables.service and then defined the rules accordingly. This time, `firewall-cmd --get-default-zone` returns `FirewallD is not running` but I can block outbound traffic.

Comment: If you've chosen to use iptables directly and have successfully blocked outbound traffic, it's possible that iptables is conflicting with firewalld. firewalld is designed to manage the firewall and can conflict with manual iptables rules.